# Do you need to put your wings at the center of gravity when building an airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, weight-and-balance

I have been wondering about this for quite a while and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 9):

For supersonic speed, putting the wings near the center of gravity would be a good start. Even better, place the wing's center slightly aft of the center of gravity in a conventional configuration.

[image: Lockheed F-104 in flight]

<sub>Lockheed F-104 in flight (picture [source](http://media.moddb.com/images/groups/1/3/2044/F104G.jpg))</sub>

If you use rotating wings, placing their roots right above the center of gravity has worked well, too, especially if there is only one attachment point for them.

[image: AS 355 Ecureuil helicopter]

<sub>AS 355 Ecureuil helicopter (picture [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/RAN_squirrel_helicopter_at_melb_GP_08.jpg))</sub>

If there is more than one attachment point, however, the rotating wings should be at opposite ends of the fuselage, quite a bit away from the center of gravity.

[image: Boeing-Vertol CH-46]

<sub>Boeing-Vertol CH-46 helicopter (picture [source](http://www.aviation-history.com/boeing/ch46-4a.jpg))</sub>

At subsonic speed it is advantageous to stretch the wings out sideways, so at least their tips are again quite a bit away from the center of gravity.

[image: Nimeta single-seat glider]

<sub>Nimeta single-seat glider (picture [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Bruno_Gantenbrink_Nimeta_D-KGYY.jpg))</sub>

And then there are some odd designs which try to separate the wings from the center of gravity as much as possible, and they still fly.

[image: Rutan Proteus tandem wing]

<sub>Rutan Proteus tandem wing (picture [source](http://static.rcgroups.net/forums/attachments/2/3/8/1/2/a3697947-99-rutan%20tandem%20wing.jpg?))</sub>

So there is no general rule. Maybe [these answers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34341/how-can-i-find-the-cg-of-a-model-aircraft-based-on-its-dimensions) help to answer your questions about wing placement relative to the center of gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not, CG is a variable.

The wing creates a center of lift (can be refered to depending on what you're trying to achieve as center of pressure or aerodynamic center).

CG works in a partnership with the center of pressure and the horizontal stabilizer to give the aircraft it's stability characteristics.

Comment: Would be good to mention the typical relation between Cg and the wings / weight and balance to give a "full" answer.

Comment: @Notts90 agreed, feel free to add to it as I have already passed my ATPL mass and balance exam 3 months ago!